# Add locally stored image to Power BI Force Directed Graph node

Tags: powerbi

I'm aware that the node image can be changed by specifying a url. However, is it possible to reference an image/icon stored locally?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are small enough then you can embed them in the file as binary data.

Create a text column from your image column along these lines:

```
"data:image/png;base64, " & Binary.ToText([Column to covert], BinaryEncoding.Base64)
```

You can then use that column in your report as images once you switch the Data Category to Image URL.

I don't have time to explain in detail at the moment, but there are a couple of blogs that do a great job.

[Blue Granite: SIMPLE STEPS TO EMBED IMAGES IN POWER BI](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/simple-steps-to-embed-images-in-power-bi)

[Gerhard Brueckl's BI Blog: Storing Images in a PowerBI/Analysis Services Data Models](https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2018/01/storing-images-powerbi-analysis-services-data-models/)

Comment: Great thanks! I'll try these out and leave a comment here on how it goes..